# Dynamic programming algorithm for finding good number

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, pseudocode

A give number x is 'good' if the sum of any two consecutive digit of the number x are between k and 2k. I need to find an algorithm that for a given number k and a given number n, find how many 'good' n-digit numbers exist.

Can someone confirm that my code is good:

```
for($i=10; $i<100; $i++) {
 if( ($i/10) + ($i%10) < $k OR ($i/10) + ($i%10) > 2*$k ) {
  $cnt++;
 }
}
$result = pow($cnt, $n-1);
```